# Bounding the norm of matrix powers

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given two square matrices $A$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\Vert A - C \Vert_2  \leq \beta$ $ \forall \beta \geq 0$, can we say anything about the upper bound of $\Vert A^ {k} - C^{k} \Vert_2$ interms of $\beta$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.  Also what is the condition for $\rho(C) < 1$, given that $\rho(A) < 1$, where $\rho$ represents the absolute maximum eigen value (spetral radius)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write
$$
A^k- C^k = (A-C)A^{k-1} + C(A-C)A^{k-2} + \dots = \sum_{j=0}^k C^j(A-C)A^{k-j-1}.
$$
Hence
$$
\|A^k-C^k\|_2 \le \|A-C\|_2 \sum_{j=0}^k \|C^j\|_2\|A^{k-j-1}\|_2.
$$

Comment: Thank you for this. But the problem is I don't have any information about matrix C and in order to get a tighter bound for this, am trying to obtain a condition to ensure C is a stable matrix, given that A is a stable matrix. By stable matrix, I mean maximum eigenvalue lying inside the unit disc. if you can think of, any such condition, please share it.